# JS return doesn't wait for await

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-2017

I am trying to use the async await.

My app starts like this

```
axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/ccidxann.php`)
  .catch(err => console.error('axios error get', err))
  .then(async res => {
    const html = res.data
    const jobList = await getJobList(html)
    console.log(' after each jobList', jobList)
    // jsonfile.writeFileSync('jobs.json', jobList, { flag: 'a' })
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
```

The problem is that `jobList` is always returned as an empty array.
Here is the `getJobList` function

```
async function getJobList (html) {
  const jobList = []

  const dom = new JSDOM(html)
  const { window } = dom
  const $ = require('jquery')(window)
  const jobsInDom = $('table').first().find('td > a')

  // AWAIT HERE
  await jobsInDom.each(async function (index, jobElem) {
    const name = $(jobElem).text()
    const url = $(jobElem).attr('href')
    // Another AWAIT HERE
    const jobDetailsHTML = await getJobDetailsHTML(`${ROOT_URL}/${url}`)
      .catch(err => console.error('getJobDetailsHTML err', err))
    const domDetails = new JSDOM(jobDetailsHTML)
    const { window: windowDetails } = domDetails
    const $details = require('jquery')(windowDetails)
    const jobDetailsHTMLBody = $details('body').prop('outerHTML')
    jobList.push({
      _id: url,
      name,
      detailsHTML: jobDetailsHTMLBody
    })
    console.log('in each jobList', jobList)
  }) //each
  return jobList
}
```

As you can see I put the `async` keyword in front of it,

and I have put the `async` keyword in the callback of `each`

and put `await` in front of all async operations.

The `console.log` in the callback of `each` prints the array filled with values

but it seems the `return` works before the `each`

even with `await` keyword in front of it.

And also here is `getJobDetailsHTML` just in case. It's a simple function and seems to work just fine

```
async function getJobDetailsHTML (url) {
    // ANOTHER AWAIT HERE
    return await axios.get(url).data
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `jobsInDom.each` is synchronous function, so putting await before doesn't give you desired effect. So somehow you need to get promise which resolved when processing is finished for all jobs, like this:

```
  // handles one element and returns promise
  const jobHandler = async jobElem => {
    const name = $(jobElem).text()
    const url = $(jobElem).attr('href')
    const jobDetailsHTML = await getJobDetailsHTML(`${ROOT_URL}/${url}`)
      .catch(err => console.error('getJobDetailsHTML err', err))
    const domDetails = new JSDOM(jobDetailsHTML)
    const { window: windowDetails } = domDetails
    const $details = require('jquery')(windowDetails)
    const jobDetailsHTMLBody = $details('body').prop('outerHTML')
    jobList.push({
      _id: url,
      name,
      detailsHTML: jobDetailsHTMLBody
    })
    console.log('in each jobList', jobList)
  }

  const promises = [];

  // start processing of each element
  jobsInDom.each((index, jobElem) => promises.push(jobHandler(jobElem));

  // wait for processing of all job elements
  await Promise.all(promises);
```